# I have some values(comma separated) in a variable. i want to insert that values in database one by one

Tags: php, mysql

My Code is given below :

```
$trend=5,6,7;
$variableAry=explode(",",$trend); 
            foreach($variableAry as $var)
            {
    $sql="insert into trending_lawyer(id,lawyers_id)values('','$var')";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Please suggest me to what to do/modify in this code to insert values in database.

Comment: Where does `$s` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about doing it something like:

```
$trend='5,6,7';
$variableAry=explode(",",$trend); 
foreach($variableAry as $var)
{
    $sql="insert into trending_lawyer(id,lawyers_id)values('','$var')";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

There are other ways to optimize you code, but, for starters, this should work for you.

Just realized that you are trying to insert id as part of insert statement, if id is a PR and AI column, you can skip it in you insert statement, so, you code will look like:

```
$trend='5,6,7';
$variableAry=explode(",",$trend); 
foreach($variableAry as $var)
{
    $sql="insert into trending_lawyer(lawyers_id)values('$var')";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: If i want to update 5 with id 1 and 6 with id 2, and 7 with id 3 . then ?

Comment: so, do you already have those id's in the table? if so, then I think you should probably be executing an update query, instead insert. If these are new values, then you should keep the id column empty, and let id be auto incremented.

Answer (score 1):

```
$variableAry = explode(",", $trend);
$sql = "insert into trending_lawyer(id,lawyers_id)values";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($variableAry); $i++) {
    $sql.="('','$variableAry[$i]'),";
}
$sql=trim($sql,',');
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

> Query looks like :

```
insert into trending_lawyer(id,lawyers_id)values('','5'),('','6'),('','7')
```

Comment: It will send only one request to inserting the data so it takes less time to performing the insert operation.